# Is it a good idea to call a staticmethod in python on self rather than the classname itself

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

If I have the following class.

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def _bar():
        # do something
        print "static method"

    def instancemethod(self):
        Foo._bar()  # method 1
        self._bar() # method 2
```

In this case, is method 1 a preferred way of calling staticmethod _bar() or method 2 in the Python world?

Comment: Is it legal to use the method 1 in the first place?

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar: Absolutely legal :)

Comment: As a rule, calling from `self` (or `cls` in a class method) will be (slightly) faster, assuming you have access to `self`/`cls` in local scope, solely because `self` will be in the locals (looked up by index in an internal array cheaply), while `Foo` will be a lookup in globals (requiring one or more checks in various namespace `dict`s to load it, slightly more expensive). Not a huge difference mind you, but it's something to consider.

Comment: @ShadowRanger is right when you're calling inside instancemethod().  I've only ever called Foo._bar() as a classmethod outside of an instance myself.

Answer (score 4):

Write the code that expresses what you want to do. If you want to call this method right here:

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def _bar():  # <-- this one
        # do something
        print "static method"
```

then specify that particular method:

```
Foo._bar()
```

If you want to call whatever `self._bar` resolves to, meaning you've actually decided that it makes sense to override it and made sure your code still behaves sensibly when that method is overridden, then specify `self._bar`:

```
self._bar()
```

Most likely, this method isn't designed to be overridden, and the code that uses it isn't designed to anticipate overriding it, so you probably want `Foo._bar()`.